# JavaScript return из callback

Tags: javascript, callback

Вопрос
Как сделать return из callback-а?

например, есть функция

```
getParams(["ArrayOfParamNames"], function(CallbackResult){
    //code
});
```

Мне нужно достать этот CallbackResult

типа

```
    function getResult(){
        getParams(["Param1","Param2"], function(res){
            //Код в колбэке
        });
        return res; // ретёрним тот самый res, который объявляли в getParams(["Param1","Param2"], function(res)...);
    }
var x = getResult()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант предлагаю использовать объект `Promise`, который используется для отложенных и асинхронных вычислений:

```
function getResult(arrOfParamNames) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return getParams(arrOfParamNames, function(CallbackResult){
      //code
      //при благоприятных условиях выполнения функции вызываем resolve
      resolve(CallbackResult)

      //иначе reject
      //отсюда выполнение попадет в catch
    });
  });
}



getResult(["Param1","Param2"])
  .then(res => {
    //при успешном выполнении
    //что то делаем с res
  })
  .catch(err => {
    //при неуспешном выполнении
    //что то делаем с err
  })
```

Подробнее почитайте [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) и [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise).

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, почему заминусовали мой ответ? Я бы мог его подкорректировать, если что-то не так.

Comment: Я не минусовал)
Ответ полезен)

Answer (score 2):

у меня вот так работает:

```
function getGeoName(message) {
        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                if (body.geonames && body.geonames.length > 0) {
                    return weather("CityName");
                }else return message.addText('Я не знаю такого города, попробуйте написать город по английски').send();
            } else return message.addText('Я не знаю такого города, попробуйте написать город по английски').send();
        })
    };
function weather(city2) {
}
```

У вас должно работать так:

```
function getResult(){
    getParams(["Param1","Param2"], function(res){
       return result(res);
    });
}
function result(){
}
```

Другой вариант:

```
var global;
setTimeout(function () {
    function getResult() {
        getParams(["Param1", "Param2"], function (res) {
            global = res;
        });
    }
}, 8000);
```

Async await пример:

```
function serialAsyncMap(collection, fn) {
        let global = [];
        let promise = Promise.resolve();
        getParams(["Param1", "Param2"], function (res) {
            promise = promise.then(() => fn(res)).then(result => global.push(result));
        });
    return promise.then(() => global);
}
```

Comment: А если перед getParams поставить return?

Comment: может просто из за асинхронности не успевает вернуть

Comment: @PauloBerezini Не помогло, либо я не так написал, либо что-то еще. Можно ли какой-нибудь глобальной переменной присвоить значение этого res?

Comment: @ДанилЧугаев Не получится

Comment: Да, можно через глобальную переменную, но учтите, что вы не знаете, когда вызовется callback. Это зависит от специфики устройства функции, куда вы передаете этот callback. Обычно, если вам нужно что-то сделать с результатами работы callback, это делается внутри самого callback вызовом еще одной функции, как в ответе. В итоге получаем гирлянды callback, за что и ругают иногда JS-код

Comment: В глобальную переменную я бы не стал класть

Comment: @wirtwelt Я как раз сделал так, чтоб мне было не важно, когда колбэк вызывается
Мне нужно просто время от времени (сэтИнтервалом) получать эти параметры, а потом, в другое время их использовать, а так как функция достаточно долгая - вызывать ее именно во время использования параметров задерживает выполнение

Comment: @PauloBerezini мне как раз нужно в глобальную, см коммент выше

Comment: Делайте глобальную переменную. Пишите из callback туда значение. В интервале читайте значение и работайте с ним, если не NULL например, и сбрасывайте значение в NULL. Тогда вы точно будете знать, что это актуальное значение, записанное из callback. Однако это похоже на костыль, вам не кажется? Если вам надо просто на новое значение делать работу - вызов функции из callback гораздо приятнее выглядит, имхо

Comment: посмотрите 3 пример-костыль

Comment: посмотрите 4 пример